# Нарисовать картинку поверх всего остального в ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

У меня есть картинка. У меня есть программа под айфон. Как написать метод, который установил бы картинку (класса `UIImage`) поверх всего остального?

**Примечание:** нужно заполнить весь экран картинкой.

Comment: Эээ ребята, а с чего бы то вопрос требует правки? Кому тут не понятна суть вопроса, когда целых три человека дали вполне правильные и приемлимые ответы? Почти все ответчики правильно поняли суть вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
imageView.image = myImage;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: да хватит уже этот ответ исправлять. если у вас есть идеи как это сделать по другому напишите свой ответ.

Comment: Зачем используется границы экрана а не `view`?

Comment: @Sk0prion в следующий раз сразу спросите, и не занимайтесь вандализмом чужих ответов. Я начну издалека: В вопросе не дается никакого контекста, на предмет зачем спрашивающему это надо, и по своему опыту (а я тут кручусь уже с пол года) я знаю, что в большинстве случаев угадать, что же на самом деле надо автору вопроса почти невозможно. Взять к примеру этот вопрос. Может человек хочет показать модальный вью, может он пишет свой alertView и ему надо затемнить все под ним и так далее. И как вы уже видите, ответ был бы разным для каждого случая `продолжение ниже`

Comment: для модального окна надо использовать модальный VC, для алерта, правильнее было бы создать отдельное окно поверх всего контента и так далее. Пришли к ответу на ваш вопрос: не зная контекст вопроса, по моему будет правильнее всего ответить на вопрос именно так, как он задан - спросил человек как заполнить `весь экран` картинкой, и получил ответ с использованием размера всего экрана, а не контроллера. Если вам кажется, что правильнее было бы использовать размер вью родительского контроллера (и я не говорю, что я с вами в этом не согласен) - напишите комментарий или свой ответ.

Comment: Я не хочу никого из новичков вводить в заблуждение. Есть `UIScreen` в котором храниться инфа о экране(размер одного пойнта, размер экрана). Брать оттуда инфу для задания `frame` в корне неверно. В том случае возможно привело к правильному результату, только потому что `view` имеет границы как у `screen`. Нужен `full-screen`: задаем границы родительского `view` (`bounds`), закидываем на этот `view`.

Comment: Не сработать это может только в одном случае - если речь идет про контроллер, который не занимает весь экран. Но в этом случае и ваш подход не сработает.

Comment: Если идет запись геопозиции или звука, сверху статус бар увеличивается в высоту. Размеры `view` и `screen` не будут совпадать.

Comment: Извини, просто такие штуки могут иногда к неправильным поведению приводить. Использовать вроде похожие вещи не по назначению. Как пример: использование `frame.size` для задания позиции элементов внутри `view`, вместо `bounds.size`. Все работает до тех пор пока не применили трансформацию к `view`.

Comment: Да, пожалуй. но это будет применимо только в ситуации, если вью создан уже после того, как статус бар увеличился, в других ситуациях оба варианта приведут к одному и тому же результату.

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идет о том как вывести картинку на первый план тогда так:

```
CGRect rect = self.view.bounds;
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bla-bla.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
imageView.image = myImage;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
```

Comment: Спасибо.Ваш вариант тоже оказался полезен для меня, но коллега дал ответ раньше.

Comment: Этот вариант более правильный

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить subview поверх всех контроллеров, в данном случае это будет UIImageView с вашей картинкой как subview окна UIWindow через стандартный addSubiew.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
   MyAppDelegate* myDelegate = (((MyAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));
[myDelegate.window addSubview: imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно прямо поверх всего всего, то лучше делать так:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject addSubview:imageView]`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Вот не уверен лучше ли =) игры на уровне `window` могут привести к печальным последствиям. Если есть возможность не делать этого, лучше сделать другим способом.